# Where can I sell stock photos as a minor?

Tags: selling, stock-photography

I want to sell my stock photos online, but I am under 16 and don't have a driver's license and would prefer not to submit my birth certificate / passport. Is there a website that does this?

Comment: In many areas you would be considered unable to enter into a contract due to age (with no offense intended you are not considered competent by legal standards, and competency is required for a contract to be valid). So you may find that any sites that will allow you, may be a bit dodgy and you may not get what you expect. If practical you would be better getting a parent to submit for you.

Comment: @Linwood That comments really belongs as an answer. Sometimes the answer is "bigger picture" than what the OP thinks they're asking.

Comment: @scottbb, perhaps, though I thought someone may actually know of such a place as asked.  If no one answers I will.

Comment: There is plenty of room for both types of answers. There is also this: [Short answers as comments — please resist the urge](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge)

Comment: *" would prefer not to submit my birth certificate / passport."* Good call.  Never give a website your passport or birth certificate.  Never supply this by email either - it's almost always scam.  As a minor there are no legitimate grounds for a website or email contact to require this info from you (and very few as an adult).

Comment: What sites require anything other than a SSN or EIN?  There's really no excuse for asking for anything else, as all the website is required to do is report monetary transactions.  (USA only; different countries no doubt are different).

Comment: @Carl Witthoft All of them, including big ones like Shutterstock and Adobe Stock.

Comment: Check '13 Your Liability' on TOS on the EYEM site (for example): https://www.eyeem.com/en/tos (I expect this will be similar for iStock, Getty and others).  Actually iStock require a minimum of 18 years of age: https://workwithus.istockphoto.com/en/FAQs

Comment: Actually, sorry check '4 Use by Minors' http://eyeem.com/en/tos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always sell them through someone you trust who's not a minor, such as your parents.  There just needs to be an adult who can sign a contract and can adopt the responsibility that the contract sets out, on your behalf.

Underage people can still earn money from their pursuits (think child actors), it's just for practical reasons there needs to be someone adult who can sign the contract for companies to do business with.

Comment: Not just "someone your trust", but someone a court would consider legally entitled to act on the minor's behalf - a parent or legal guardian.  Minors can void contracts so you can't rely on contractual obligations made by a minor alone.